# Save column value to file SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I save first column from first row from query to file without additional character?
When I save data like this:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT ''xxx'' " queryout D:\file.txt -w  -T -S OMD-MG\SQL2008R2'
```

I've got:
[additional \r\n at the end of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STv0u.png)

When I save data like that:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT ''xxx'' " queryout D:\file.txt -N  -T -S OMD-MG\SQL2008R2'
```

I've got:
[additional characters at front of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcDI1.png) I think this is length

I try many parameter without satisfied result

Is there other option to save data to file from query without designer or management studio with correct data?

Comment: I correct last question to be more precise. I want save correct data in result without additional characters.

Comment: just run first command - no any additional characters, may be problem not only in SQL Server? and second as well

Comment: @a_vlad check non printable characters at the end

Comment: I mean - I not see any character on my both results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-N` is a native binary format where any nullable or variable length fields are preceeded by their length. If you use `-N` with a non nullable, fixed-width field it will not be preceeded by its length.

If you want text data without the newlines you could try `-r ''` to specify the row terminator which is `\n` by default, e.g.:

```
bcp "select 'xxx'" queryout test.txt -c -t '' -r ''
```

..at least in SQL Server 2016 CTP I'm seeing that BCP tries to add padding to varchar columns. If you convert to text it seems to work alright:

```
bcp "select convert(text, col) from table" queryout file -c -t '' -r ''
```

Comment: `bcp "select 'xxx'" queryout test.txt -c -t "" -r ""` works (double quotes) but when query from column _varchar(8000) not null_ I get value filled with spaces

Comment: @siwydym67 it looks like bcp has some strange behavior with varchar.. if you convert the column to text it should eliminate the padding chars

Comment: Any idea to save binary without additional characters (length prefix)? cast to image not working.

Comment: @siwydym67 the only way I know of to get binary output with no prefix is with -N and fixed-width, non-nullable columns. I don't think casting will do it - you'd have to define a temp table with a fixed-width non-nullable binary column and then dump that with -N